# How to get index/position of the tag using text in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

For example, consider the below `html` tags, where I need to get the exact index/position of the text, `three`

```
<tr>
 <td>one</td>
 <td>two</td>
 <td>three</td>
</tr>
```

The expected value is '**3**'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# This is an actual bin with a test page in it.
driver.get("http://jsbin.com/wagonazipa")

# Obviously, this needs to be precise enough to find the tr 
# you care about. Adapt as needed.
tr = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("tr")

# Find the element you care about. You might want to use td rather 
# than *.    
target = tr.find_element_by_xpath("*[. = 'three']")

# Get all the children of the row.
children = tr.find_elements_by_xpath("*")

# Get the index of target in the children list.
print children.index(target)
```

Python's implementation of Selenium is such that you can do comparisons between `WebElement` objects with `==` and thus `index` works. If you are working with a language that does not do this, you'd have to get the identifier that Selenium assigns to each `WebElement` object. On Python that's the `.id` property. In other languages you have a `getId()` or `get_id()` method to get the id. Then you can compare `WebElement` objects by identifier.

If the jsbin becomes inaccessible, this is the relevant HTML in it:

```
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
      <td>three</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example for the same using **`JAVA`**,

```
driver.get("http://www.indiabookstore.net/");

WebElement list = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right']"));        
WebElement li = list.findElement(By.xpath("*[. = 'Offers']"));        
List<WebElement> children = driver.findElements(By.tagName("li"));        
System.out.println(children.indexOf(li));
```